# pwn with only realpath(), without write()

Tags: c

It's an pwn challenge. And I only got an elf and libc.

The programe run on linux(x64).

It protect by NX. PIE and canary was off.

In the ELF, there only have main(), realpath(), read().

Without write or puts

In main(), there only an read(), and it have stack overflow leak.

It have a function hint(), in this function, it call readpath("/proc/self/exe", &resolved)

```c
int main(){
  ...
  read(0, &buf, 0x200uLL);
  return 0;
}
```

```c
char hint(){
  char resolved[50];
  return realpath("/proc/self/exe", &resolved);
}
```

Now, I don't know what should I do. I want to leak the address and get the baselibc, but there was not write() or puts().

Can anyone give me some help? Just tell we what should I learn.

Comment: `return realpath("/proc/self/exe", &resolved);` You must be new to C?

Comment: I don't quite understand the big picture here, but note that if you rename (or link) the executable to some very long file or pathname, then `realpath` will overflow the `resolved` buffer.  Eg `mv foo asdfasdf....asdfasdf ; ./asdfasdf....asdfasdf`

Answer (score 0):

hei?  don't do this....
if I guess right, this is the challenge pwn222 of syc-geek Challenge 2020?!
I am the author of this pwn challenge.
I will announce wp and exp at the end of the game.
emmm，note the challenge hint，

The game is still going on，
**Please don't discuss it now,  thanks.**